# (Anti)commutation of creation and annhilation operators for different fermion fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, commutator, grassmann-numbers, anticommutator

The Fourier expansion of the fermion field operator is such that

$$ \hat\psi=\int\!d^3p\,\left[  f_b(p)\hat b(p) +f_d(p)\hat d^\dagger\!(p) \right]  ~~, $$

for some sufficiently complicated $f_b$ and $f_d$.  The operators $\hat b^\dagger$ and $\hat b$ create and destroy electrons respectively, and $\hat d^\dagger,\,\hat d$ work the same for positrons.  I haven't seen it stated explicitly, but I assume both $b$ operators commute with each $d$ operator.  What is an efficient way to show, for instance,

$$ \hat b^\dagger\hat d^\dagger\big|0\big\rangle= \hat d^\dagger\hat b^\dagger\big|0\big\rangle~~? $$

Any demonstration that $b$ and $d$ commute would suffice if another is more direct, $[\hat b,\hat d]=0$ for instance.

Comment: Careful, if you're talking about a *fermion* field you will be dealing with *anti*-commutators rather than commutators.

Comment: My question is whether or not $\hat b$ commutes with $\hat d$ and $\hat d^\dagger$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you (and Tony Zee) are correct and I am being an idiot.  You do need a different $b$ and $d$! Obviously  (in retrospect) $\psi\ne \psi^\dagger$.  The $d$ and $b$  anticommute
$$
\{b_k,d_{k'}\}=0\\
\{b^\dagger_k,d^\dagger_{k'}\}=0\\
\{b^\dagger_k, d_{k'}\}= 0\\
\{d^\dagger_k, b_{k'}\}= 0\\
\{b^\dagger_k, b_{k'}\}= (2\pi)^32 E_k \delta^3(k-k')\\
\{d^\dagger_k, d_{k'}\}= (2\pi)^32 E_k \delta^3(k-k')
$$

What you are calculating
$$
\langle P_1|\psi\gamma^\mu \psi|P_2\rangle 
$$
should end up as something like $v^\dagger(P_1)\gamma^0 \gamma^\mu v(P_2)$.

Comment: Can you please write some (anti-)commutation brackets involving $\hat b$ and $\hat d$?

Comment: How about $\{b_k,b^\dagger_{k'}\}= 2E_k \delta^3(k-k')$, and $\{b_k,b_{k'}\}=0$?  As I said, there are no $d$'s as for electron and positrons they are the same as the $b$'s, but with $b$ and $b^\dagger$ interchanged.

Comment: Then if I have some expression with both in it, can I rewrite all the $\hat d$ as $\hat b^\dagger$, and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, You will need to include  a charge conjugation matrix of course. You will need to read about that in a field-theory textbook.

Comment: Lets say I want to compute $\langle P_2| \bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi |P_1\rangle $, which is the context of my question.  I insert the Fourier expansions of $\psi$ and $\bar\psi$ in the middle and after I multiply them, I get some string with $\hat b$'s and and $\hat d$'s in it, some with daggers.  Within that string, can I treat the $\hat b$'s  and $\hat d$'s as commuting operators?  Can  I move $\hat b$'s past $\hat d$'s with impunity?   Since the book I'm following hasn't mentioned the charge conjugation matrix relationship, I don't think I need it right now.  (QFT by Zee.)

Comment: No. They anticommute, and moving a $b$ past a $b^\dagger$ gives you an additional c-number.

Comment: Ok.  Why is this term equal to zero?  I am missing an important detail somewhere.  $\int\!d^3p'\!\int\!d^3p''\,\big\langle 0\big|\hat b(P_2)\hat d(p')v^\dagger(p')    \gamma^0\gamma^\mu \hat d^\dagger(p'')\hat b^\dagger(P_1)v(p'')  \big|0\big\rangle$

Comment: There is no obvious reason for it to be zero. Who says that it is?  It is not a term that arises from $\bar\psi \gamma^\mu \psi$ as it includes four Fermi fields rather than two.

Comment: Note that the expression for the electron field  $\psi$ in your original question is incorrect. The $d^\dagger$ should be  a $b^\dagger$.

Comment: This is my source for the equation.  It is in Zee, page 109: https://tinyurl.com/y2es44x4.  If this is wrong, can you cite a source with the correct formula?  What do you mean by four fields?  Do you mean the four momenta?  I used $\hat b^\dagger(p)|0\rangle=|p\rangle$ to get them from $\big\langle P\big| \bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi  \big|p\big\rangle$.

Comment: Actually you (and Tony Zee) are correct and I am being an idiot.  I have changed my answer!